# Splitting one column into 3 then inserting into a table

Tags: sql-server

Hello recently I have been trying to split one column containing `[city, state zip]`
and then insert into the same table only in separate columns being `[city]` `[state]` `[zip]`.

format of the column varies : `[New York, VA 50000]`or it could be something like `[New York, West Virginia 50000-0000]`. Is there an easy way to do this I've tried using sub strings, but I am not having much luck!

Comment: left till the 1st `,` reverse the string, left till the 1st space (reverse result) that would give you the city and zip, then use a replace function twice to eliminate the city, zip trim the results and you have your state.  Though I'd bet someone could come up with a regular expression that's faster. I'm just not proficient with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parsename...

```
declare @a varchar(100) = 'New York, VA 50000'

select parsename(replace(@a,', ','.'), 2) as [State], parsename(replace(parsename(replace(@a,', ','.'), 1),' ','.'), 1) as ZipCode, parsename(replace(parsename(replace(@a,', ','.'), 1),' ','.'), 2) as City
```

Comment: I like the idea, I'm just not sure I see a comma between state and zip and replacing all spaces with ,'s wouldn't work for those multi name cities. or states.  unfortunatly I can't get SQL Fiddle to work with SQL server or Id test out my concerns.

Comment: Else we need to use split using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns/39376747#39376747 and then add into different columns

Answer (score 0):

It will be a little difficult if your "State" names aren't all in 2-letter abbreviations. I would try to do a REPLACE() on those values first to normalize them all, then start separating out the values.

To get the zip codes that are only 5 digits long you can use:

```
substring(fieldname,len(rtrim(fieldname))-5,5) ... WHERE substring(ZipCode,len(rtrim(zipcode))-5,1)!='-'
```

Then modify it for the ones that have a dash and additional 4 digits:

```
substring(ZipCode,len(rtrim(ZipCode))-10,10) ... WHERE substring(ZipCode,len(rtrim(zipcode))-5,1)='-'
```

You can use the same SUBSTRING() to get the State out, after you set them to the same length. Provided, it's messy but it will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I tried as follows to solve your requirement:

```
DECLARE @LOCATION TABLE (LOCATION VARCHAR(200))
DECLARE @NEW_LOCATION TABLE (CITY VARCHAR(200),STATE VARCHAR(200),ZIP VARCHAR(200))

INSERT INTO @LOCATION VALUES('[New York, VA 50000]')
INSERT INTO @LOCATION VALUES('[New York, West Virginia 50000-0000]')

INSERT INTO @NEW_LOCATION 
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(LOCATION,0,CHARINDEX(',',LOCATION)),'[',''),
        REPLACE(REPLACE(LOCATION,SUBSTRING(LOCATION,0,CHARINDEX(',',LOCATION)+1),''),
                REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(LOCATION),0,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(LOCATION)))),''),
        REPLACE(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(LOCATION),0,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(LOCATION)))),']','')
        FROM @LOCATION

SELECT * FROM @NEW_LOCATION
```